# How to check the whether the javascript is minified or not

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying to implement minification and concatenation in my Worklight project.

I followed the steps that were given in the IBM Worklight Information Center and Concatenation is working however Minification worked.

Where to check whether the js and css files are minified or not.

Comment: Also how to give multiples files at different path in the includes attributes in minification

Comment: Also when i concatenate the files it is applying for both js and css files.But the minification is not applying for any files in the includes in the minification tag.Help me with that too.\

Comment: When try to concatenate giving specific includes in the the build_setting.xml all the files gets concatenated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reading materials:**
Please make sure to thoroughly read these. Some of your questions are answered there (and below...).

- [Concatenation of JS and CSS files](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_concatenation.html)
- [Minification  of JS and CSS files](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_minification.html)

**Follow the below steps** to verify minification is working for you.
This is what I've done:

1. Created a new Worklight project, "minification"
2. Created a new Worklight application, "testapp"
3. Added the Mobile Web environment

   - Note: For minification and concatenation only Mobile Web and Desktop Browser environments are supported.
4. In `build-settings.xml` I have added the Mobile Web environment
5. Pointed the `includes` field to: `**/js/testapp.js`

   - Note: Use a semicolon `;` to separate entries: `**/js/*;testapp.css`

   [image]
6. Right-clicked the Mobile Web environment folder and then on `Run As > Apply build settings... > Use minification to reduce the size of JavaScript and CSS files > Save and run`
7. Copied `myProject\bin\testapp-mobilewebapp-1.0.wlapp` to the Desktop
8. Extracted it (it's basically a zipped file) and looked at `www\default\js\testapp.js`

The copyright notice is not removed (legal stuff, it's on you to remove that beforehand if you choose so), but whitespaces and comments have been removed.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

Comment: What is officification and how to implement it in worklight. I searched for officification in the ibm information center and i couldnt find any relevant information about it.So can you help me with it

Comment: There is no such thing as "officification". Please make sure the spelling is correct.

Comment: Sorry Then it must be obfuscation.So what is mean by obfuscation?